# allow users view own objects in django admin

Tags: django, permissions, django-admin

i want give access to users to admin panel

i have a table :

```
class Todo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

i want just allow users to see,edit,add and delete their own objects in admin panel not others.
i wrote this:

```
class TodoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super(TodoAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        queryset = queryset.filter(user = request.user)
        return queryset
```

but didnt work.
how can i do that?

Comment: where from did you get that ModelAdmin has method called queryset ?

Comment: In other questions...is there anyway to do that?

Comment: You dug up some old question answer that is why I am asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to override `get_queryset` method as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset)

> The get_queryset method on a ModelAdmin returns a QuerySet of all
> model instances that can be edited by the admin site. One use case for
> overriding this method is to show objects owned by the logged-in user:
>
> ```
> class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
>     def get_queryset(self, request):
>         qs = super().get_queryset(request)
>         if request.user.is_superuser:
>             return qs
>         return qs.filter(author=request.user)
> ```